# Update optional integer cannot delete all digits

Tags: swiftui

I think i cannot delete all digits because of my variable optional int. And when updating its automatically saves data. So when i delete all digits its getting nill and swift wont let me delete all digits and leaves 1 digit.

```
            Text("Print Length:")
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
            TextField("Print Length...", value: $book.printLength, format: .number)
                .padding(6)
                .padding(.leading,6)
                .background {
                    Color("customSubBackground")
                }
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .shadow(radius: 1)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.9)
```

i can change to nonoptional but i want to see TextField("Print Length..." this part "Print Length..." when i change to nonoptional, in add view shows default value instead of Print Length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can use a separate non-optional variable for displaying the placeholder text while keeping the printLength variable optional for data storage. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
@State private var userInput: String = ""
@State private var printLength: Int?

TextField("Print Length...", text: $userInput, onEditingChanged: { editingChanged in
    if !editingChanged {
        if let length = Int(userInput) {
            printLength = length
        } else {
            printLength = nil
        }
    }
})
.padding(6)
.padding(.leading,6)
.background {
    Color("customSubBackground")
}
.cornerRadius(5)
.shadow(radius: 1)
.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.9)
```

But this is just one way. Using .overlay(), you can keep the desired text “in the field”, operating with it as you please, depending on whether the user interacts with the field or not. And the original value of the text field, then you can leave it in the form " " Then, getting nil, you can

```
  TextField("", text: Binding(
                     get: {youOptionalValueFromModel ?? ""},
    set: {...}
    ))
    ...
```

Comment: @OVERNIND my question is i can't delete all digits so i want to be capable of. But this works too with nonoptinal variable.